# JQuery append element removes all html dom elements

Tags: jquery, append

I have a filter system setup and I'm struggling with jquery .append.

When the user interacts with the filter system, the visible results are removed from the dom and then distributed evenly in `<div class="col-1"> ... <div class="col-2">... <div class="col-3">...`

It's done this way because the page outputs staff in a vertical manner, but the filtering must reorder horizontally. You'll see what I mean when you use the first filter.

Please view this page:
[demo page](http://simondouglas.com/stackexchange/woodworks)

1. Click on Event Sponsor
2. Then click on East

The function that I'm talking about is `reflowVisibleResults()` 
Basically visible results are copied to an array and then removed from the document only to be then reflowed left to right in col-1,col-2,col-3

The whole page is replaced with just a phone number. If you go to line 917 and switch the above line over it works as expected. I just can't figure out how to actually output html from an array of jquery objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Parker, you code seems way overcomplicated for what it needs to be. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/HrYLr/) is quick sample of how I would do it.

I am sure it can be optimized and polished quiet a bit, but that should be enough to get you on the right path.

Comment: Thank you very much, very elegant. I will step through what you done.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you are over complicating the problem. i created a filter system similar to this but i used jQuery [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) or [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) methods to achieve the results.

It only took me two lines of jquery to create the filtering system.